# MVC Call Javascript func from Razor code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I can't call a func I wrote in the script from the Razor code where I pass the parameters to the controller.

Anyone have any Idea ?

MyCode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetDropDownValue(ControlId) {
    var list = document.getElementById(ControlId); 
    return list.options[list.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

```
@Html.DropDownList(
   "TransactionType",
   new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Forex.Reports.ReportValueType))),
   "Transaction Type",
   new
   {
       @class = "form-control",
       @id = "type"
   })

//This is the parameter where I try to invoke the Javascript func                                    
@using (Html.BeginForm("MonetaryTransactions", "Trading",new { type =
"GetDropDownValue('type')" }))
{
<input type="submit" value="D"/>
}
```

Thanks,
Yaniv

Comment: are you trying to get the selected dropdown item on form submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer for my question by myself:

You can get the value of the control you are using (In my case DropDownList) by subscribing its event in jQuery that invokes Ajax function, The Ajax will post the parameter retrieved from the event to the Action and then you can use it in the action as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     // Defining jquery func
     jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
         // Subscribing the control event by it's #id
         $("#type").change(function () {
             // Defining ajax func
             $.ajax({
                 // Setting url for posting
                 url: "@Url.Action("MonetaryTransactions", "Trading")",
                 // Setting the Http Request to Post
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 // Posting the control seleced value to the action
                 data: { Selected: $("#type").val() },
                 success: function (data) {
                     // success code if needed
                 }
             });
         });
     }); 
</script>

// The DropDownList control
@Html.DropDownList(
   "TransactionType",
   new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Forex.Reports.ReportValueType))),
   "Transaction Type",
   new
   {
       @class = "form-control",
       @id = "type"
   }
)
```